# AVL Tree - why retrace after insertion

Tags: algorithm, tree, avl-tree

I am confused by the code for insertion operation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#cite_note-Sorting_and_searching-9).
In short, I can't think of an example that it is necessary to do the retracing after insertion. Because insertion always happens in a leaf node, say `Z` is inserted to node `X`. The first/earliest violation of the invariant for AVL tree (balance factors must be within [-1, 1]) can only happen in `parent(X)`. After we rebalance this small subtree that only contains `Z`, `X`, and `parent(X)`, the height of this small subtree will be the same as before and don't have any influence to all other nodes.

Why do we need a loop that go all the way up to the root?

```
for (X = parent(Z); X != null; X = parent(Z)) { // Loop (possibly up to the root)
// BalanceFactor(X) has to be updated:
if (Z == right_child(X)) { // The right subtree increases
    if (BalanceFactor(X) > 0) { // X is right-heavy
        // ===> the temporary BalanceFactor(X) == +2
        // ===> rebalancing is required.
        G = parent(X); // Save parent of X around rotations
        if (BalanceFactor(Z) < 0)      // Right Left Case     (see figure 5)
            N = rotate_RightLeft(X, Z); // Double rotation: Right(Z) then Left(X)
        else                           // Right Right Case    (see figure 4)
            N = rotate_Left(X, Z);     // Single rotation Left(X)
        // After rotation adapt parent link
    } else {
        if (BalanceFactor(X) < 0) {
            BalanceFactor(X) = 0; // Z’s height increase is absorbed at X.
            break; // Leave the loop
        }
        BalanceFactor(X) = +1;
        Z = X; // Height(Z) increases by 1
        continue;
    }
} else { // Z == left_child(X): the left subtree increases
    if (BalanceFactor(X) < 0) { // X is left-heavy
        // ===> the temporary BalanceFactor(X) == –2
        // ===> rebalancing is required.
        G = parent(X); // Save parent of X around rotations
        if (BalanceFactor(Z) > 0)      // Left Right Case
            N = rotate_LeftRight(X, Z); // Double rotation: Left(Z) then Right(X)
        else                           // Left Left Case
            N = rotate_Right(X, Z);    // Single rotation Right(X)
        // After rotation adapt parent link
    } else {
        if (BalanceFactor(X) > 0) {
            BalanceFactor(X) = 0; // Z’s height increase is absorbed at X.
            break; // Leave the loop
        }
        BalanceFactor(X) = –1;
        Z = X; // Height(Z) increases by 1
        continue;
    }
}
// After a rotation adapt parent link:
// N is the new root of the rotated subtree
// Height does not change: Height(N) == old Height(X)
parent(N) = G;
if (G != null) {
    if (X == left_child(G))
        left_child(G) = N;
    else
        right_child(G) = N;
    break;
} else {
    tree->root = N; // N is the new root of the total tree
    break;
}
// There is no fall thru, only break; or continue;
}

// Unless loop is left via break, the height of the total tree increases by 1.
```

Comment: Imagine the root has one child to the left, and a child with two grandkids to the right. That tree is sufficiently balanced to be a valid AVL tree. If you add another node to the right of the root, then you can't balance the tree without rotating the root.

Comment: I see. So if an AVL tree becomes unbalanced after insertion or deletion, we only need to do a single rotation or double rotations at the earliest violated spot, and then we can stop. This is what `break` does in the code. Is it correct?